# SharePoint 2010 slow compiling with claims authentication

Tags: 2010, security-token-service

I don't know why, but the Security Token Service Application is extremely slow on my latest SP 2010 installation. The first time it needs ages to access a site. After about one minute i receive the error below. Any ideas why it needs that long?

```
Request for security token failed with exception: System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9491024. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.TimeoutException: The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9640000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out    
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:     
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown
 at [0]:     
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)    
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo)
```

[image]

Comment: We have the same issue - after either an IISReset or stoping and restarting the STS web service site and app pool, it consistently times out the 1st time, then works fine afterwards. Did you ever get an answer or resolve this issue? Our issue is more prevalent on Development than Production - we have a 3-tier environment, so STS runs on both the front-end server and the admin/index/app server. Thanks,
John